# How to change chosen radio button?

Tags: android, dialog, radio-button, onclicklistener

I have a custom dialog with 3 radio buttons (in RadioGroup) and I'm trying to set different sounds for each button. I want to have a default button with a specific sound and when pick another one and press an OK button, the sound will change. I tried a method with switch but the app is crashing.

Here is the xml for the dialog:

```
<RadioGroup
    android1:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android1:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RadioButton
        android1:id="@+id/radio1"
        android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android1:text="cow" />

    <RadioButton
        android1:id="@+id/radio2"
        android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android1:text="dog" />

    <RadioButton
        android1:id="@+id/radio3"
        android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android1:checked="true"
        android1:text="cat" />

</RadioGroup>

<Button
    android1:id="@+id/ok"
    android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android1:text="OK" />
```

Here is the java code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    frequency = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.frequency);   

    frequency.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialogFrequency();
        }
    });
}

public void dialogFrequency (){

        dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setTitle("Choose Frequeny:");
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialog);

                    Button ok = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ok);
        // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
        ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }


public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.radio1:
            if (checked)
                radio1.setChecked(true);
                radio2.setChecked(false);
                radio3.setChecked(false);
            break;

        case R.id.radio2:
            if (checked)
                radio2.setChecked(true);
                radio1.setChecked(false);
                radio3.setChecked(false);
            break;

        case R.id.radio3:
            if (checked)
                radio3.setChecked(true);
                radio1.setChecked(false);
                radio2.setChecked(false);
            break;

        default:
            return true;;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the android developer documentation:

> The Dialog class is the base class for dialogs, but you should avoid
>   instantiating Dialog directly.

For your situation an AlertDialog would be the best option. The developer API guide give a good introduction on how to [build an AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog).

You could achieve your frequency selection by [adding a list](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingAList), or if you want to stick with your RadioButton concept you can [create a custom layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout) for your AlertDialog.

Comment: ty for answering, but i already got the answer from a different place, by using custom dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Dialog`, use `AlertDialog` instead.

Here is a brief example showing radio buttons using `AlertDialog` :

#### activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.androidhuman.example.sampleapplication.app.MainActivity">

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:text="Open dialog" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

#### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button btn;
    AlertDialog dlg;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

    dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Custom dialog")
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // User pressed OK
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Pressed OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", null) // Do nothing if pressed cancel
        .setSingleChoiceItems(new String[]{"Radio1", "Radio2", "Radio3"}, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            switch(which){
                case 0:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Radio1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Radio2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Radio3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }).create();

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        dlg.show();
        }
    });

    }
// Leaving out remainings...
```

Shows following dialog :

[image: Screenshot_alertdialog_radio]

Comment: i wanna use cutom dialog and i need to infulance the mp file that played in the mainactivity and thats not helping me.

Comment: If you want a customized view of the dialog,  you can just use AlertDialog.Builder.setView() instead of using helper methods.